# Dart - The return type of '' cannot be inferred

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, record

```
The return type of '' cannot be inferred.
Declare the return type of ''.dart(inference_failure_on_function_return_type)
```

I am getting the above error when i create a record inside a class but i dont get error when i use this code inside build method.

```
 ( final String combination, final ProductType productType,  final StockOrderType stockOrderType){
    return (combination, productType, stockOrderType);
  }
```

Comment: Please post a minimal but complete example that can reproduce the problem that you're encountering.